error No module named ''pyautogui'' when executing .exe - pyinstaller
I tried to convert the python file to exe with pyinstaller both in the virtual environment and normally, but when I try to run the exe in the dist folder, I get the error No module named ''pyautogui''.
Also, when I just run the code "pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole "main.py"", it compresses all the libraries I have installed on my computer into the exe and creates an exe file of about 2GB. That's why I tried to do it by creating a virtual environment.
I tried  --hidden-import=pyautogui but it's does'nt worked for me. What can i do now ?
I still get this error  No module named ''pyautogui''

Have you tried checking and reinstalling pyautogui? You can use something like pip in command prompt to do so

I tried. Didn't work

Do you have multiple versions of python installed? If so, try loading up the other one, or see the path where pip is installing to, and check that it is the correct version of python
